# numpy loadtxt raise IOError("%s not found." % path) OSError: uest1.txt not found

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

My code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.loadtxt('uest1.txt',delimiter=',')
print(a[0:4,:])
```

Error:

```
F:\LearnPython>python -u "c:\Machine learning\bai3\bai3.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Machine learning\bai3\bai3.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = np.loadtxt('uest1.txt',delimiter=',')
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 961, in loadtxt
    fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 195, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 535, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: uest1.txt not found.
```

Comment: Please add more details like what you're trying to achieve and what's the error acting as a blocker for you? Please go through the StackOverflow guidelines to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this `uest1.txt` file present in the current directory in which python code is being written?

Comment: Try including the full file path.